# No such prime ideal contains $I_1+I_2\implies I_1 $ and $I_2$ are relatively prime

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

It's clear to me that if $I_1$ and $I_2$ are two relatively prime ideals of a ring $R$, then there is no such prime ideal containing $I_1+I_2$, since by definition of relatively prime ideals $I_1+I_2=R$ and by definition of a prime ideal P, $P\neq R$

I'm wondering whether the converse is also true, i.e if no prime ideal $P$ contains the ideal $I_1+I_2$, then would that imply that $I_1$ and $I_2$ are relatively prime.

Comment: every ring has a unit, but in my case it has both an additive and multiplicative unit.

Comment: I see, so $I_1$ is contained in the maximal ideal $P_1$ and $I_2$ is contained in the maximal ideal $P_2$. Both $P_1$ and $P_2$ must be prime ideals. If $P_1\neq P_2$ then clearly $I_1+I_2$ isn't contained in a single prime ideal. But can we use this to show that $I_1$ and $I_2$ are relatively prime

Comment: by claiming that $I_1+I_2\neq R$, we have $I_1+I_2$ contained in a maximal ideal, so $I_1+I_2$ is contained in a prime ideal, contradiction :)

Comment: So the converse is only true when there is a unit in the ring, but I don't understand, don't all rings have a unit by definition, also I don't recall using the unit property in my proof